# Exim outbound mail - whitelist domains

Tags: email-server, exim

I am using Exim version 4.91. How do I configure it to block outbound emails except for few domains?

Basically, the mail server should only send emails to users on example.com, example.net & example.org. Emails to any other domains have to be blocked.

Answer (score 2):

Add a stanza to the beginning of the routers section (order is important, as the first router to match is used):

```
deny_domains:
  driver = redirect
  domains = ! example.com : ! example.net : ! example.org
  allow_fail
  data = :fail: Mailing is only allowed to example.com, example.net and example.org
  no_more
```

This router will match other domains than those listed due to the negation exclamation marks, the `data` `:fail:` tag indicates that this is a failure.

The `no_more` directive stops exim trying other routers for the matched domains.

Comment: The slightly better approach is to place the restriction into the ACL like `acl_rcpt` to prevent any further proceeding. Also negation by exclamation mark can be moved to the left like `!domains = a : b : c`.